# Set Drawable instance to Image in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, who can tell me is there a way to assign a Drawable Object to the Image compose view?

I took the apps installed on an Android device. I get an icon with the type that is Drawable and I want to use it in Image

```
val icon: Drawable = packageInfor.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
```

I found there are 3 functions that can assign images

> - From Painter (IdRes)
> - From ImageBitmap
> - From ImageVector

[image]

From all that I don't know how to assign a Drawable instance.

Comment: there is a `Drawable.toPainter()` function in the [accompanist library](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/imageloading-core)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After all, I found a simple solution with Accompanist. Thanks to @Sinner of the System for suggesting to me.

Adding this dependency to the app gradle.

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-drawablepainter:<version>" //0.28.0
```

Using:

```
Image(
    painter = rememberDrawablePainter(drawable = drawable),
    contentDescription = "content description",
)
```

Check out: [Drawable Painter¶](https://google.github.io/accompanist/drawablepainter/)

Comment: It can't show all Drawable from `applicationInfo.loadIcon` use Coil as @lase said.

Answer (score 13):

**Edit**: You should definitely use the [accompanist library](https://google.github.io/accompanist/drawablepainter/) as recommended in the Wilson Tran answer. Since it provides support for several kinds of drawables.

If you're not using the accompanist library, you can do the following...

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(LocalContext.current, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)?.let {
    Image(bitmap = it.toBitmap().asImageBitmap(), contentDescription = null)
}
```

You can set the drawable size in `toBitmap` function if you want...

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the [Coil library](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/), `rememberImagePainter` will accept an `Any?` as its data argument, which includes support for `Drawable` instances. I'm using this as an all-in-one solution for my images rather than importing Accompanist.

```
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(data = myDrawableInstance)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could convert drawable in to imageBitmap

```
val icon = appInfo.loadIcon(packageManager).toBitmap().asImageBitmap()

Image(
        bitmap =  icon!!,
        contentDescription = "app icon",
        modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
    )
```

like this

p.s. Accompanist library works fine. but this way you don't need to add any external library

Answer (score -1):

You can do like that

```
 val backgroundImage = painterResource(R.drawable.your_image)
```

and then pass this to your image like that

```
 Image(painter = backgroundImage, contentDescription = null)
```

That will work.

Comment: The Drawable object is taken from the PackageInfo not from the resouce id

Answer (score -1):

We can simply put drawable resource like below:

```
Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_half_rect_croner),contentDescription = null, tint = Color.Red)
```

Comment: This would seem to suffer from the same problem as Rajshekhar's answer.